# Are .Net and Java interfaces similar enough to consolidate somehow?

Tags: java, .net, interface

In an environment with both .Net and Java code, it seems that one way to consolidate the two is to use (or at least look at) common interface files in order to share a high level understanding of the business logic in an organization.

Java and .Net are different from a technical perspective, but by sharing interfaces they can focus on common business logic, while leveraging the advantages of OOP.

Is it common in any sense for an organization to implement an architecture based on having interfaces that are applied to both .Net and Java code and would it be possible to create (or does one exist) a syntax converter for interface code, so they can be easily shared by both  frameworks?  Or are these two frameworks so completely different that it would be counterproductive to share interfaces?

Comment: Uhm wait, do you mean to provide an API with both Java and .Net versions?

Comment: That's not what I meant, but it might help to know the answer to that too.

Comment: I don't know C# well but I know it well enough to know the syntax isn't directly compatible, e.g. C# uses `:` instead of `extends/implements`, and has a concept of property signatures, among other things. I'm not sure how much you'd gain by by combining the two, except maybe for the purpose of code analysis later. It may be easier to generate both C# and Java from some common other source definition instead of trying to make a generic translator. I did find [this](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CSharp_to_Java_Converter_Details.html?gclid=CNWUzPGco70CFYuXOgod2RMA4g).

Comment: By the way, I'd be careful about invoking the "at odds with one another" thing, you're likely to distract from your real question and invite a little bit of flamery. There's thousands of programming languages out there, C# and Java just happen to be two of them. Also you may want to move this question to http://programmers.stackexchange.com. Maybe.

Comment: I thought I'd get a better answer here, and thanks, I removed the "at odds line".  It wasn't appropriate.  We have both .Net and Java developers and I want us to share business logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See IKVM:

IKVM.NET is an implementation of Java for Mono and the Microsoft .NET Framework. It includes the following components:

A Java Virtual Machine implemented in .NET

A .NET implementation of the Java class libraries

Tools that enable Java and .NET interoperability

IKVM makes it possible to develop .NET applications that use Java API's. Here's how to proceed:

IKVM comes with an implementation of the Java class libraries in .NET. To use those API's, simply add a reference to IKVM.OpenJDK.ClassLibrary.dll to your Mono / .NET IDE project.
To use other Java API's, you can take one of the following approaches:
Convert the Java API to .NET CIL using ikvmc. This produces a .NET dll that you can reference in your project.
Use the Java reflection API's to dynamically load and execute the Java bytecode using the IKVM bytecode interpreter. For example, your application can load Java bytecode over a network connection and execute it dynamically.

http://www.ikvm.net/

Comment: I used their language converter and it worked in converting a simple c# interface code snippet to Java.  That might be all that's needed.